# Black traces on screen

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am building a simple pizza slicing game in Unity. I have a Sprite with a collider attached as the pizza, and whenever I drag the mouse over the collider, it gets an enter point and an exit point and draws a transparent line between them, pretty much like this:

[image]

The problem is, whenever I move the pizza, the line leaves some sort of trace behind it, even if I disable the line renderer or the whole pizza game object. The only solution I have found for this, is to resize the game window, and everything goes back to normal.
Also, if I play my game in maximized mode, the screen fills with black lines, which is very odd. As before, if I resize my game window everything goes back to normal. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this problem? Or, at least, go around it by resizing the game window somehow from the script, during play mode? I already tried resizing the camera and changing the resolution, but it does not change anything.

This is how I draw the lines:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{
    enterPoint = LineDrawer.instance.mousePos;
    enterPoint.z = 0;

    points.Add (enterPoint);

}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{


    exitPoint = LineDrawer.instance.mousePos;
    exitPoint.z = 0;
    points.Add (exitPoint);


    GameObject obj = new GameObject ();
    GameObject instance = Instantiate (obj, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    Destroy (obj);

    instance.transform.SetParent (transform);
    instance.name = "Cut";

    linerenderer = instance.AddComponent<LineRenderer> ();
    linerenderer.material =  new Material(Shader.Find("Diffuse"));
    linerenderer.useWorldSpace = false;
    linerenderer.SetWidth (0.15f, 0.15f);
    linerenderer.SetVertexCount (2);
    linerenderer.SetPosition (0, enterPoint);
    linerenderer.SetPosition (1, exitPoint);

}
```

Comment: Show us your relevant code please. Ideally something which allows us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I updated the post.

Comment: Please update your post to include it.

Answer (score 0):

The problems that I can see here are:

1. You should not give `Quaternion.identity` when you create it. You are making it a child. It should have the same rotation with the parent, or else your local positions won't work:

`GameObject instance = Instantiate (obj, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;`

2. You are not using world space for the line. I bet your `enterPoint` and `exitPoint` are in world space. Try this:

`linerenderer.SetPosition (0, linerenderer.transform.InverseTransformPoint(enterPoint));
    linerenderer.SetPosition (1, linerenderer.transform.InverseTransformPoint(exitPoint));`

3. Why are you doing all this in Trigger functions? There is no if, so these functions execute whenever the pizza hits anything.